# Azure上のC#（MVC）WEBアプリを参照する際に、Azure AD B2CでMFA認証してからメイン画面に遷移したい

Tags: c#, azure, model-view-controller

AzureのApp Serviceを使った既存のWEBシステムにアクセスする際に、
特定のネットワークからのアクセスでは既存のWEBシステムのメイン画面に遷移し
それ以外はAzure AD B2CのMFA認証画面を表示してから、MFA認証成功後にメイン画面へ遷移するようにしたいのですが
MFA認証後の認証状態が正しく取得できず、メイン画面に遷移することができません。
既存のWEBシステムはC#(.Net6)MVCモデルで開発されています。

※下記イメージの挙動としたく、青矢印のアクセスフローは既に稼働しており、オレンジのフローを新たに設けたい。
[image: ![画像の説明をここに入力]

これを実現するために、認証スキームの登録が必要と理解し下記の通り Startup.cs に追記しました。
※「services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication」以降が追加したロジックで、それ以前は既存ロジックです。

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "MyScheme";
}).AddCookie();
services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(_configuration, "AzureAdB2C", OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, "b2cCookies");
services.AddControllersWithViews().AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
services.AddOptions();
services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(_configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C"));
```

そしてメイン画面のControllerに、IPアドレスを判断し"会社のIPアドレス以外 かつ Azure B2C認証がない場合"はAzure B2CのMFA認証画面に遷移するよう下記ロジックを追加しました。

```
public IActionResult Main()
{
    string ipAddress;
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        ipAddress = client.GetStringAsync("https://ipinfo.io/ip").Result;
    }
    List<string> allowedIPs = new List<string> { "192.168.1.100", "192.168.1.200" };
    if (!allowedIPs.Contains(ipAddress) && !User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        string redirectUri = Request.GetDisplayUrl();
        string authenticateUrl = $"{_configuration["AzureADB2C:Instance"]}/{_configuration["AzureADB2C:Domain"]}/{_configuration["AzureADB2C:UserFlowName"]}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p={_configuration["AzureADB2C:UserFlowName"]}&client_id={_configuration["AzureADB2C:ClientId"]}&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri={redirectUri}&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login";
        return Redirect(authenticateUrl);
    }
    else
    {
        if (HttpContext.Session.GetString(AccountConst.M_AUTH_USER_ID) != null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Top");
        }
        return View("Main");
    }
}
```

上記修正によって特定のIPアドレス以外からWEBシステムにアクセスした際に、Azure AD B2CのMFA認証画面を表示することは出来ましたが
認証に成功しても、再度メイン画面のControllerのMain関数が呼び出された際に
「User.Identity.IsAuthenticated」がfalseのままであるため、メイン画面の表示に移らず認証画面を表示してしまいます。
どのように修正すれば正しい認証ステータスを取得できるでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

以下のコードで実現できないでしょうか？

```
public IActionResult Main()
{
    string ipAddress;
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        ipAddress = client.GetStringAsync("https://ipinfo.io/ip").Result;
    }
    List<string> allowedIPs = new List<string> { "192.168.1.100", "192.168.1.200" };
    if (!allowedIPs.Contains(ipAddress) && !User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        string redirectUri = Request.GetDisplayUrl();

        return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            RedirectUri = redirectUri
        }, OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }
    else
    {
        if (HttpContext.Session.GetString(AccountConst.M_AUTH_USER_ID) != null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Top");
        }
        return View("Main");
    }
}
```

また、クライアントのソース IP は、リバースプロキシを経由していないのであれば、以下のように取得できます。

```
 var remoteIpAddress = HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
```